# How to access the object-members of an object declaration in kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Say you have the following, nested object declaration:

```
object Father {   
    val fathersField = "value"
    object Child {
        val childsField = 3.141592654
    }
}
```

When I use reflection starting from `Father`, I'm able to find the field `fathersField` only but no member referencing the `Child` instance.

Is it possible to find those inner object declarations via reflection? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`nestedClasses`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/nested-classes.html) from `kotlin-reflect`:

```
Father::class.nestedClasses.find { it.simpleName == "Child" }
```

Or, as @s1m0nw1 suggested, use the Java reflection and convert the `Class` back to `KClass` with [`.kotlin`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#kclass) if needed:

```
Father::class.java.classes.first { it.simpleName == "Child" }.kotlin
```

Comment: Oh my, that's it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

That's it:

```
println(Father.javaClass.classes[0])
>> class packagepath.Father$Child
```